# A probability problem I am trying

Tags: probability

Suppose $X_i$ are iid Bernoulli with parameter $p$, $0<p<1$. and $N$ is Poisson $\lambda$, and $N$ is independent of $X_i$. Let $S_N=X_1+X_2+\dots+X_N$. Find the distribution function and hence the pmf of $S_N$.

What I tried :
$P(S_N=x)$ happens when $x$ of the $X_i$ are $1$ and rest are $0$. But then I don't have an idea how to incorporate that $N$ is Poisson. I did it like any ordinary problem which gives binomial$(N,p)$ which is not the right answer I think. Can someone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$S_n$ is binomial for a given n: $S_n\sim \mathcal{B}(n,p)$

$N$ is poisson: $N\sim \mathcal P(\lambda)$

Use: $$\begin{align}
\mathsf P(S_N=x)
& = \mathsf P(\bigcap_{n=x}^\infty (S_N=x\cap N=n)) & \text{since $\forall n< x:\mathsf P(S_N=x\cap N=n)=0$}
\\[1ex]
 &= \sum_{n=x}^{\infty} \mathsf P(S_n=x)\mathsf P(N=n) & \text{by law of total probability}
\\[1ex]
 & = \sum_{n=x}^\infty {n\choose x}p^x(1-p)^{n-x}\cdot\frac{\lambda^n{\sf e}^{-\lambda}}{n!} & \text{by substituting distribution formula}
\\[1ex]
 & = \frac{{\sf e}^{-p\lambda}(p\lambda)^x}{x!} & \text{by Wolframalpha}
\end{align}$$

Comment: The idea is correct. But I suppose there's a typo in the line "by substituting distribution formula", why is it $\binom{n}{x}p^n$, it should be $\binom{n}{x}p^xq^{n-x}$?

Comment: @shadow10  Quite right, it should.  Correction made.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use the law of total probability to break up $P(S_N=x)$ into the cases where $N$ is equal to every possible integer:
$$
P(S_N=x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty P(S_N=x|N=k)\cdot P(N=k)
$$
Then each $P(S_N=x|N=k)$ is just $P(S_k=x)$, for a constant $k$, which you can compute.